# I want to make dynamic titles like in WordPress

Tags: html, build, wordpress-theming

there is an option in wordpress in which inside brackets "{}" the word changes depending on the search term, how can I do the same on my page? without using wordpress

Answer (score -1):

i don't think you want to do that with pure html and css. [take at look at this sample](http://%20https://codepen.io/zystvan/pen/waQvmj).

Happy coding :)

Comment: I can use php or js, thx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).